# Querying an Oracle Date field using a string in NHibernate HQL

Tags: nhibernate, oracle10g, hql

I'm trying to query a .NET DateTime property and compare it with a date string like so:

```
SELECT cat FROM mydll.cats AS cat
WHERE cat.BirthDay > '1999-02-20'
```

When I'm trying to search by a date **string** (without the SetDate function)
The query won't run saying I canno't compare a **String** to a **Date**.

Is there a way or a certain format I can use to compare my date with a simple string
(Maybe something like the ToDate function in Oracle SQL..)
*I need to separate the HQL string from the NHibernate engine because of design issues

Thanks a lot [=

Comment: Why do you need to compare string to date? why not date to date?

Comment: I'm using the QueryEngine [link](http://hillside.net/europlop/HillsideEurope/Papers/EuroPLoP2004/2004_Wellhausen_QueryEngine.pdf)  design pattern and I don't want my HQL transformer to be type specific..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to_date` function is mapped in the Oracle dialect, so:

```
SELECT cat FROM mydll.cats AS cat
WHERE cat.BirthDay > to_date('1999-02-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```