# How to get YEAR from a DATETIME using DATEPART in HQL

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, hql

I'm new user in StackOverflow, and I need a help in a HQL string..

In SQL my query is something like this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(yyyy, Moment) AS Year,
FROM PRODUCT_SOURCE
```

How can I convert this to HQL?

I've tried this, but didn't work..

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(year, p.Moment) as Year, " + 
        "FROM Product_Source as p";
```

Comment: I don't know much about NHibernate, but your code will generate a List of DateTime, right? You can't get the year from the .NET DateTime object?

Comment: `to_date(p.moment, 'yyyy')`? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5132624/1176601

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for your answer.. But I was thinking in retrieve only a unique year description (using DISTINCT).. But, I've made this in C# programming..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>I am basing this on SQL2008 dialect so change as you see fit.</strike>

```
public class MsSql2008ExtendedDialect : MsSql2008Dialect
{
  public MsSql2008ExtendedDialect()
  {
    RegisterFunction("DATEPART_YEAR", 
      new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.DateTime, "datepart(year, ?1)"));
  }
}
```

And to use you would use your HQL like this

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART_YEAR(p.Moment) as Year, " + 
        "FROM Product_Source as p";
```

**Edit** As Diego quite righly points out most of the functions in MSSQL server are already registered. For a full list see https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2000Dialect.cs

So just use:-

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT year(p.Moment) as Year, " + 
        "FROM Product_Source as p";
```

Comment: Thanks Diego, found the file in source where these functions are registered.

Answer (score 1):

The `year` function is already mapped internally, so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year(p.Moment) as Year,
FROM Product_Source as p
```

This is registered by the `MsSql2000Dialect` (from which newer MSSQL dialects inherit).

Now, this assumes `Product_Source` is the name of your class, which is odd, as it doesn't follow the usual .NET conventions (you should drop the underscore)